# Directory synchronization: TotalCommander will not synchronize all files

Tags: sync, total-commander

I ran Commands / Synchronize dirs in TotalCommander, but after synchronization it still refuses to synchronize few files. Why?

The screenshot is posted below. The red files are those problematic files - they actually are different, already exist in the target directory, new version is available, but when I click on "Synchronize", TotalCommander won't do anything.

[image]

I use version 7.55 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I had the option "ignore date" checked! When this option is checked, you must do what @Bohuslav is suggesting, i.e. manually add these files to synchronization. But when I uncheck this option, it works as expected, i.e. the newer files are synchronized automatically!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you have files with same name/location but different content you have to explicitly select the action you want to do with those files before synchronization.

For example, select all files and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, which will copy all the conflicting files from left to right panel after you hit Synchronize (which seems to be what you need, given that the files in the left panel are newer).

You can also choose other actions (just right click the file to see the list of options).

Comment: But why? this is the point of synchronization, no? To update older files with newer version of them! So it shouldn't ask, and I think in the past, this problem was not present.

Comment: Ahh, got it work, see my answer! Thank you very much though, this explicit action would be an interesting feature to use.

Comment: @Tomas Glad you resolved it. I had no idea about the effect of ignore date option, +1 for your solution

Comment: Thanks Bohuslav. Your answer brought me to that idea! I was thinking that TotalCommander is completely buggy :)